# Vs2011 beta display hangs

Tags: visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio 2011 beta and it seemed to install fine apart from the display badly lags begind control input, the display doesnt refresh and I need to hover my mouse over the code editor window like an etch a sketch. I've tried to tweak all the display settings btw: i5/GeForce 415M,  single/dual monitor. refresh is 60hz.

Any ideas appreciated.

Edit:

Update: Here was the fix for me - Right Click VS launcher, Run using -> Integrated Graphics.

Comment: Are you confident it is supposed to handle as well as "normal" software? Pre-release software sometimes comes with poor rendering behavior -- sleeps between paints, etc. -- to try to make other mistakes more obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm confident in the software, it runs perfectly in vmware and amazon images - its weird this would happen on a 1 year old laptop with a reasonable gfx card.